# July 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, election, events

In connection with the moderator elections, we held a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This was be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation was completely voluntary. I had worked with the candidates to find a time that allowed the most participation.

*The Town Hall Chat took place Thursday the 19th at 04:00:00Z UTC / 7:00 AM Israeli Time / Midnight EDT.*

- [View in other timezones.](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=7&day=19&year=2012&hour=4&min=0&sec=0&p1=0) (Note that this is Wednesday in most of the United States.)
- [Join the room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4146/judaism-town-hall-chat)
- **[Read the chat digest.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1271)**

---

Here are the details:

- The Town Hall Chat was a one-hour event.
- The format was an open discussion.  Users were encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.

Comment: A few points: 1) What if there is no primary phase? 2) Do to our geographic user distribution it might be best to schedule it around both USA and Israeli time zones. 3) Can there be a way to submit questions before hand to be asked during the chat for those who will not be able to attend?

Comment: @DoubleAA (1) We will still hold a Town Hall Chat, it'll just be at the start of the "election" phase. (2) In the email, we will be setting up a schedule. My priority, first and foremost, will be based on the moderator's timetables. If you don't mind, give me the timezone code of Israel and I'll add it extra in the scheduling display for everyone. (3) We prefer not to have questions pre-loaded, but if you'd like, some questions can be left with someone to ask (I'm fine asking on behalf of people who cannot attend).

Comment: GraceNote Thanks for your quick response. Israel is GMT+2 plus another one nowadays for DST.

Comment: @GraceNote, thanks for the schedule-wrangling!  What's the best way for people who can't be there then to participate? Informal discussions in the regular chat room, keep the special chat room open longer, something else?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Please see [Answering Town Hall Chat sessions that you could not attend](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120877) (well, for candidates; for users I guess informal discussion in the regular chat room is preferred, or provide us a few questions in advance and someone will try and sneak them in as Grace mentions above)

Comment: @TimStone, great thanks!  I'm going to try my best to be there (maybe I can take a nap earlier so I don't mind my 7:30AM meeting :-) ), but it's good to have a fallback.

Comment: Point of order: are the questions pointed at specific candidates, or to all and then each answer, or to all and then one answers?

Comment: @DoubleAA Either or. Generally it's more general questionaire, but if you have specific candidate concerns, it's better to voice them than to stay silent.

Comment: Perhaps the chatroom should be renamed Mi Yodeya Town Hall Chat?

Comment: @TimStone, that MSO post makes it sound as though the Q&A will be copypasted here after the chat. Is that true? Is there a purpose to that, considering that chat rooms automatically archive themselves?

Comment: @msh210 Organization. Compare how easy it is to read [this digest](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest) versus [the transcript of that event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3744/2012/6/13).

Comment: @GraceNote, thanks for organizing the townhall.